# Bootstrapping a vector of results, by group in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

**Question**: How can I use a boostrap to get confidence intervals for a collection of
statistics calculated on the eigenvalues of covariance matrices, separately for
each group (factor level) in a data frame?

**Problem**: I can't quite work out the data
structure I need to contain these results suitable for the `boot` function, or a way to "map" the bootstrap over groups and obtain confidence intervals in a form suitable for plotting.

**Context**:
In the `heplots` package, `boxM` calculates Box's M test of equality of covariance matrices.
There is a plot method that produces a useful plot of the log determinants that go into this
test.  The confidence intervals in this plot are based on an asymptotic theory approximation.

```
> library(heplots)
> iris.boxm <- boxM(iris[, 1:4], iris[, "Species"])
> iris.boxm

        Box's M-test for Homogeneity of Covariance Matrices

data:  iris[, 1:4]
Chi-Sq (approx.) = 140.94, df = 20, p-value < 2.2e-16

> plot(iris.boxm, gplabel="Species")
```

[image: plot of log determinants for Iris data]

The plot method can also display other functions of the eigenvalues, but no theoretical
confidence intervals are available in this case.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(5,4,1,1))
plot(iris.boxm, gplabel="Species", which="product")
plot(iris.boxm, gplabel="Species", which="sum")
plot(iris.boxm, gplabel="Species", which="precision")
plot(iris.boxm, gplabel="Species", which="max")
par(op)
```

[image]

Thus, I would like to be able to calculate these CIs using a boostrap, and display them in the corresponding plots.

**What I've tried**:

Below are functions that boostrap these statistics, but for the total
sample, not taking group (`Species`) into account.

```
cov_stat_fun <- function(data, indices, 
            stats=c("logdet", "prod", "sum", "precision", "max")
            ) {
    dat <- data[indices,]
    cov <- cov(dat, use="complete.obs")
    eigs <- eigen(cov)$values

    res <- c(
        "logdet" = log(det(cov)),
        "prod" = prod(eigs),
        "sum" = sum(eigs),
        "precision" = 1/ sum(1/eigs),
        "max" = max(eigs)
        )
}

boot_cov_stat <- function(data, R=500,  ...) {
    boot(data, cov_stat_fun, R=R,  ...)
}
```

This works, but I need the results **by group** (and also for the total sample)

```
> iris.boot <- boot_cov_stat(iris[,1:4])
>
> iris.ci <- boot.ci(iris.boot)
> iris.ci
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 500 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = iris.boot)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic             Studentized     
95%   (-6.622, -5.702 )   (-6.593, -5.653 )   (-6.542, -5.438 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   (-6.865, -5.926 )   (-6.613, -5.678 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Some BCa intervals may be unstable
>
```

I also have written a function that calculates the separate covariance matrices for each group,  but I can't see how to use this in my bootstrap functions. Can someone help?

```
# calculate covariance matrices by group and pooled
covs <- function(Y, group) {
   Y <- as.matrix(Y)
   gname <- deparse(substitute(group))
   if (!is.factor(group)) group <- as.factor(as.character(group))

   valid <- complete.cases(Y, group)
   if (nrow(Y) > sum(valid)) 
      warning(paste(nrow(Y) - sum(valid)), " cases with missing data have been removed.")
   Y <- Y[valid,]
   group <- group[valid]
   nlev <- nlevels(group)
   lev <- levels(group)
   mats <- aux <- list()
   for(i in 1:nlev) {
      mats[[i]] <- cov(Y[group == lev[i], ])
   }
   names(mats) <- lev
   pooled <- cov(Y)
   c(mats, "pooled"=pooled)
}
```

**Edit**:
In a seemingly related question, [Bootstrap by groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028727/bootstrap-by-groups), it is suggested that an answer is provided by using the `strata` argument to `boot()`, but there is no example of what this gives. [Ah: the `strata` argument just assures that strata are represented in the bootstrap sample in relation to their frequencies in the data.]

Trying this for my problem, I am not further enlightened, because what I want to get is **separate** confidence intervals for each `Species`.

```
> iris.boot.strat <- boot_cov_stat(iris[,1:4], strata=iris$Species)
> 
> boot.ci(iris.boot.strat, conf=0.95, type=c("basic", "bca"))
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 500 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = iris.boot.strat, conf = 0.95, type = c("basic", 
    "bca"))

Intervals : 
Level      Basic                BCa          
95%   (-6.587, -5.743 )   (-6.559, -5.841 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Some BCa intervals may be unstable
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can run your bootstrap function by group as follows:

```
library(boot)
library(tidyverse)

# Pooled
iris.boot <- boot_cov_stat(iris[,1:4])
iris.ci <- boot.ci(iris.boot)

# By Species
boot.list = setNames(unique(iris$Species), unique(iris$Species)) %>% 
  map(function(group) {
    iris.boot = boot_cov_stat(iris[iris$Species==group, 1:4])
    boot.ci(iris.boot)
  })

# Combine pooled and by-Species results
boot.list = c(boot.list, list(Pooled=iris.ci))

boot.list
```

> ```
> $setosa
> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
> Based on 500 bootstrap replicates
>
> CALL : 
> boot.ci(boot.out = iris.boot)
>
> Intervals : 
> Level      Normal              Basic             Studentized     
> 95%   (-13.69, -11.86 )   (-13.69, -11.79 )   (-13.52, -10.65 )  
>
> Level     Percentile            BCa          
> 95%   (-14.34, -12.44 )   (-13.65, -11.99 )  
> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
> Warning : BCa Intervals used Extreme Quantiles
> Some BCa intervals may be unstable
>
> $versicolor
> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
> Based on 500 bootstrap replicates
>
> CALL : 
> boot.ci(boot.out = iris.boot)
>
> Intervals : 
> Level      Normal              Basic             Studentized     
> 95%   (-11.37,  -9.81 )   (-11.36,  -9.78 )   (-11.25,  -8.97 )  
>
> Level     Percentile            BCa          
> 95%   (-11.97, -10.39 )   (-11.35, -10.09 )  
> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
> Warning : BCa Intervals used Extreme Quantiles
> Some BCa intervals may be unstable
>
> $virginica
> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
> Based on 500 bootstrap replicates
>
> CALL : 
> boot.ci(boot.out = iris.boot)
>
> Intervals : 
> Level      Normal              Basic             Studentized     
> 95%   (-9.467, -7.784 )   (-9.447, -7.804 )   (-9.328, -6.959 )  
>
> Level     Percentile            BCa          
> 95%   (-10.050,  -8.407 )   ( -9.456,  -8.075 )  
> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
> Warning : BCa Intervals used Extreme Quantiles
> Some BCa intervals may be unstable
>
> $Pooled
> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
> Based on 500 bootstrap replicates
>
> CALL : 
> boot.ci(boot.out = iris.boot)
>
> Intervals : 
> Level      Normal              Basic             Studentized     
> 95%   (-6.620, -5.714 )   (-6.613, -5.715 )   (-6.556, -5.545 )  
>
> Level     Percentile            BCa          
> 95%   (-6.803, -5.906 )   (-6.624, -5.779 )  
> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
> Some BCa intervals may be unstable
> ```

Comment: This looks like it is right on target.  I'm away at a conference so can't test it out right now.  To provide a **self-contained, canonical** answer that I'll accept and award the bounty, could you edit your answer to also show  the result of using something like `broom::tidy(boot.list)`, ie, what the result looks like as a data frame that can be used for a plot.

Comment: `broom` doesn't have a method for tidying `bootci` objects, but I'll whip something up later today.

Comment: OK, I'll accept your effort on this and award the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best general answer will be an extension of what @eipi10 proposed, using some method to extract the required confidence intervals from the `bootci` objects.  This is lacking from the `broom` package.

As an instructive alternative, I tried using `broom::tidy()` on the results of the bootstrap directly.  Rather than the (typically asymmetric) confidence intervals, it gives the bootstrap estimate as `statistic`, a `bias` and a `std.error`.  However, from the results I get (see below), I have doubts about whether `broom::tidy()` gives correct results in this case.

```
# try just using tidy on the bootstrap results

## pooled
iris.boot <- boot_cov_stat(iris[,1:4])
iris.pooled <- tidy(iris.boot)
```

Giving:

```
> iris.pooled
       term   statistic          bias    std.error
1    logdet -6.25922391 -0.0906294902 0.2469587430
2      prod  0.00191273 -0.0001120317 0.0004485317
3       sum  4.57295705 -0.0382145128 0.2861790776
4 precision  0.01692092 -0.0005047993 0.0016818910
5       max  4.22824171 -0.0329408193 0.2815648589
>
```

Now, use the method described in the other answer to `map` this over groups,
and combine:

```
## individual groups
boot.list2 = setNames(unique(iris$Species), unique(iris$Species)) %>% 
  map(function(group) {
    iris.boot = boot_cov_stat(iris[iris$Species==group, 1:4])
    tidy(iris.boot)
  })

# Combine pooled and by-Species results
boot.list <- c(boot.list2, list(Pooled=iris.pooled))
```

Transform to a data frame:

```
## transform this list to a data frame, with a group variable
result <- bind_rows(boot.list) %>% 
    mutate(group = rep(c( levels(iris$Species), "Pooled"), 5)) %>%
    arrange(term)

> result
        term     statistic          bias    std.error      group
1     logdet -1.306736e+01 -3.240621e-01 4.660334e-01     setosa
2     logdet -1.087433e+01 -2.872073e-01 3.949917e-01 versicolor
3     logdet -8.927058e+00 -2.925485e-01 4.424367e-01  virginica
4     logdet -6.259224e+00 -9.062949e-02 2.469587e-01     Pooled
5        max  2.364557e-01 -6.696719e-03 4.426305e-02     setosa
6        max  4.878739e-01 -6.798321e-03 8.662880e-02 versicolor
7        max  6.952548e-01 -6.517223e-03 1.355433e-01  virginica
8        max  4.228242e+00 -3.294082e-02 2.815649e-01     Pooled
9  precision  5.576122e-03 -5.928678e-04 8.533907e-04     Pooled
10 precision  7.338788e-03 -6.894908e-04 1.184594e-03     setosa
11 precision  1.691212e-02 -1.821494e-03 2.000718e-03 versicolor
12 precision  1.692092e-02 -5.047993e-04 1.681891e-03  virginica
13      prod  2.113088e-06 -4.158518e-07 7.850009e-07 versicolor
14      prod  1.893828e-05 -3.605691e-06 6.100376e-06  virginica
15      prod  1.327479e-04 -2.381536e-05 4.792428e-05     Pooled
16      prod  1.912730e-03 -1.120317e-04 4.485317e-04     setosa
17       sum  3.092041e-01 -1.005543e-02 4.623437e-02  virginica
18       sum  6.248245e-01 -1.238896e-02 8.536621e-02     Pooled
19       sum  8.883673e-01 -1.500578e-02 1.409230e-01     setosa
20       sum  4.572957e+00 -3.821451e-02 2.861791e-01 versicolor
>
```

This gives something that can now be plotted, supposedly corresponding to the plot in the original question shown without error bars:

```
result %>% mutate(Pooled = group == "Pooled") %>%
    filter (term != "logdet") %>%
    ggplot(aes(y=statistic, x=group, color=Pooled)) +
    geom_point(size=2.5) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=statistic-2*std.error, 
                      ymax=statistic+2*std.error), width=0.4) +
    facet_wrap( ~ term, scales="free") +
    coord_flip() + guides(color=FALSE)
```

[image]

However, this "tidy plot" seems **evidently WRONG**.  Theory says that the result for the Polled sample must in every case be intermediate between those for the separate groups, because it is in some sense a 'convex combination` over groups.  Compare the plot below with that given in the original question.  (It is possible that I did something wrong here, but I can't see a flaw.)